# Open pipe coming out of basement floor diagonally

Tags: basement, pipe

I'm trying to identify an old pipe coming out of the basement floor at an angle. It's not capped, but I haven't tried putting anything down it either. It's an old house (mid-1900s), so I'm wondering if it's part of some discontinued utility or if there's any issue leaving it be. [image: pipe1][image: pipe2]

Comment: Since there don't seem to be complaints about smells coming out of it, it's probably not sewer. It could be an abandoned water line. Beg, buy, borrow, rent a boroscope to look down there as far as you can, hopefully to the other end. You may run into a metal or mud cap, or you might find something else.

Comment: History would help.  There are two different floor types there, and what might have been a wall.  Do you know any of the history of it?   What's in the direction the pipe goes?  How far to an outside wall?   What's the size of the pipe, can you measure the inner diameter?   Looks like about 2 inch.  Could be a large gas pipe, or an agricultural water pipe ... are you on a farm?  Or a stormwater discharge.  Was there a sump pit nearby ever?  Is there a 3-4 inch sewer riser in the direction of the pipe?

Answer (score 1):

I have a pipe just like that in my 1940 home.

For me, it leads to a dry well.

My washing machine drains into the pipe so that I don't overload my septic tank.

Comment: 2" cast iron? Catch basin, +1. Smash it with a hammer. Stuff a bag in it and put half a gallon of concrete over it, and wave good bye.

Comment: @Mazura Why would you get rid of a perfectly good dry well? Especially if on septic.

Comment: Because it's a pipe sticking out of the floor that only exists to trip on and let rats in. Whatever fed it is long gone, and nothing new should ever go to it. But if you're on septic (which is not a part of my thought process for sewage as a city boy) leaving it be for future use isn't a bad idea. But if you have city sewer; we don't do catch basins anymore; unsanitary.

Comment: @Mazura Yeah, living on something larger than a postage stamp has advantages and disadvantages.